# In which situations I must serialize command's objects in WPF ?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

Today, I have read that command's object in WPF can be serialized.
And I'm interesting in another question:

In which situations I must serialize command's objects?
Why I need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an option to restore it to a certain state at another time, i for one never serialized commands. You can serialize pretty much any object, the point is that commands are objects while events are a list of method references.

Answer (score 1):

Never met with situation where you need actualy serialize `Command` object.
`Command` object is *application runtime*  artifact by it's nature and does not need any persistancy.

`Command` object helps to organize notifications/events interaction between different layers of your MVVM application and also manage some UI components using its `Cancel` property.

So don't see *any* need in serializing/restoring it.